# How to calculate digit containing in string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, types

I have a function and I want to calculate digit that contains in a string.

```
str='hel4l4o';
```

The code that I created:

```
function sumDigitsg(str) {
var total=0;
if(isNaN(str)) {
  total +=str; 
  console.log(total);
}
  //console.log(isNaN(str));
  return total;

}
```

Comment: what is your expected output and what do you mean by "calculate digit"?

Comment: expected output 8 after adding 4 + 4 from string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using regex to match all digits (`.match(/\d+/g)`) and then use `.reduce` to sum the digits matched:

```js
const str = 'hel4l4o';
const total = str.match(/\d+/g).reduce((sum, n) => sum + +n, 0);
console.log(total);
```

As for your code, you need to loop through your characters and then check if it is a number using `if(!isNaN(char))`. After that you need to turn the character into a number by using something like the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) (`+char`) such that you can add it to `total`:

```js
let str = 'hel4l4o';

function sumDigitsg(str) {
  let total = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let char = str[i];
    if (!isNaN(char)) {
      total += +char;
    }
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(sumDigitsg(str));
```

Comment: can u please help me to answer this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409738/how-to-returns-correctly-matched-array-containing-dna-pairs